VueJS 3 .vite Error Loading module from `node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk*` blocked because of a disallowed MIME type ("") FireFox
I have a VueJS 3 application with Pinia stores and Primevue JS library hosted in an EC2 bucket and recently out of no where I am getting these errors that are preventing the page from loading, oddly it's only some pages. The page is: https://dev.hyperwaterbids.com/bidboard/.
It seems to work fine in Chrome, but not in Firefox.
Errors that I'm getting:
Error 1:
 GET
https://dev.hyperwaterbids.com/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-QMOCFC7W.js?v=4e15f6ce
NS_ERROR_CORRUPTED_CONTENT

Error 2:
Loading module from “https://dev.hyperwaterbids.com/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-NUM5SG7I.js?v=4e15f6ce” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“”)

Erorr 3:
TypeError: error loading dynamically imported module: https://dev.hyperwaterbids.com/src/pages/bidboard/index.vue

vite.config.ts:
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'
import VueRouter from 'unplugin-vue-router/vite'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vite.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    VueRouter({}),
    vue(),
  ],
  server: {
    watch: {
      usePolling: true
    },
    port: 8082,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    hmr: {
      overlay: false
    }
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    exclude: ['primevue', '@primevue/core/api', 'axios']
  },
  base: "./",
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
})
 



Can you reproduce locally?

@kissu no, everything works fine locally.
